# How widely used is SOA?

Tags: soa, bpel

We've been having a discussion at work over how widely used SOA is.  We've been building our businesses processes using SOA for a few months now with varying degrees of success and the question came up about how widely used this architecture is.  My manager believes that "most" of the big companies are using SOA and it is gaining steam among the industry, is cutting edge technology and everybody will doing it shortly. I argued that it seemed to be the new buzzword about 2-3 years ago and was never widely adopted.

Does anybody feel strongly one way or another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SOA is an easy, standard way to write web services that other middleware (and user-space code) can use.  If you need to integrate existing code/services with web clients or other middleware clients, its a good thing to consider.

You didn't mention much about what you're trying to accomplish or what technologies you need to integrate, but I have written Oracle SOA web services that are consumed by Android in the mobile sphere, Spring in the web sphere, and other Oracle SOA clients in the enterprise sphere.

All depends on what you're looking to do, but SOA is more of a concept - and a borderline standard for integration architecture, that presupposes any particular implementation.

Comment: And, incidentally, we have a database trigger that calls into the SOA realm.  So its even useful in the back end.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538710/reports-in-soa-business-intelligence-service-oriented-architecture ?